# Restrict Azure ARM Deployment to Library templates

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

is it possible to restrict an AD user/group to only be able to deploy ARM templates which were shared with them in the ARM Template library by a PowerUser?

the user should have not other rights (maybe not even seeing the template code?) but should be able to deploy it

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is - no.
The long answer is - yes, kind of.

To do this you would restrict users access to Microsoft.Deployments Provider and allow access to [managed application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/managed-application-overview).

That would allow you to gate users to deploy only pre approved templates, basically. But that would require a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

You can also look at using Policies on Resource Groups to limit what the users can deploy